# Two css class border on the one part left

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors, border

I have to class

```
<div class="thread-entryresponse">
<div class="date">


 </div>
 </div>
```

then

```
<div class="thread-entrymessage">
<div class="date">
</div>
 </div>
```

my css code is

```
.thread-entryresponse {
    border-left: 2px solid #428bca;
    color: #444;
    padding: 10px; 
}

.thread-entrymessage {
    border-right: 2px solid #444; 
}

.date {
    color: #444;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px; 
}
```

I am trying to do below

1. if `.thread-entryresponse` and `.date` then `border-left: 2px solid #428bca;` on the date
2. if `.thread-entrymessage`  and `.date` then  `border-right: 2px solid #444;`
   on the date

note that the date is inside of the thread-entryresponse and thread-entrymessage

Comment: Are your divs nested or siblings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I strongly recommend you learn basics in HTML/CSS

Second, you can use this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/cjV74/1/)**

```
.thread-entryresponse .date {
    border-left: 2px solid #428bca;
}
.thread-entrymessage .date {
    border-right: 2px solid #444;
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry i lay it out wrong it was                               <div class="thread-entryresponse">
<div class="date">  </div> </div>  i saw it work in your demo but didn't work on my page

Comment: @user3606549 what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

As you say:

> `.date` is inside of the `.thread-entryresponse` and `.thread-entrymessage`

This means that .date is a descendant of `.thread-entryresponse` and `.thread-entrymessage`. To vary the style of `.date` according to its parent, use the descendant selector:

Markup:

```
<div class="thread-entryresponse">
    <div class="date"></div>
</div>


<div class="thread-entrymessage">
    <div class="date"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thread-entryresponse .date {
    border-left: 2px solid #428bca;
}

.thread-entrymessage .date{
    border-right: 2px solid #444;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Max_Hallinan/eSxd2/)

Comment: Ah, in the time I posted this, an answer was accepted. Sorry to repeat.